# Why the imageView which is in "userProfilePic" id, changes quickly to the old one stored in database, after selecting a new picture

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I want to change the picture in the imageView id "userProfilePic" to the new one selected by the user, and update that picture to the database. But once I choose a new picture, the image under "userProfilePic" id quickly changes to the new one and again it changes to the old one( which is already in the database) so I am unable to upload new pictures for the "userProfilePic" id. I am a beginner to Android development and I know only small amount of android, So please help me to solve this issue. This is my `EditUserProfile.java file`

```
 package com.example.kasun.timetable;

    import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.util.Base64;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.DatePicker; 
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
    import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
    import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;

    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.net.URLConnection;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.Locale;

    public class EditYourProfile extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
        private static final int Result_Load_Image=1;
        private Button bSave2,bBack2,bImageUpload;
        private EditText etUsernameEdit,etFirstNameEdit,etLastNameEdit,etPasswordEdit,etPositionEdit,etBirthDateEdit,etQualificationEdit,etEmailEdit;
        private Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        private UserLocalDatabase userLocalDatabase;
        private ImageView userProfilePic;

        private static final String SERVER_ADDRESS="http://172.21.18.170/Timetable/";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_your_profile);

            bBack2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bBack2);
            bSave2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bSave2);
            etUsernameEdit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUserNameEdit);
            etFirstNameEdit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etFirstNameEdit);
            etLastNameEdit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etLastNameEdit);
            etPasswordEdit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPasswordEdit);
            etEmailEdit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etEmailEdit);
            etQualificationEdit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etQualificationEdit);
            etPositionEdit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPositionEdit);
            etBirthDateEdit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etBirthDateEdit);
            userProfilePic=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.userProfilePic);
            bImageUpload=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bImageUpload);

            bSave2.setOnClickListener(this);
            bBack2.setOnClickListener(this);
            userProfilePic.setOnClickListener(this);
            bImageUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
            userLocalDatabase = new UserLocalDatabase(this);



            final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                      int dayOfMonth) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                    myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                    myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                    updateLabel();
                }

            };

            etBirthDateEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    new DatePickerDialog(EditYourProfile.this, date, myCalendar
                            .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                            myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();


                }
            });






        }
        private void updateLabel() {

            String myFormat = "MM/dd/yy"; 
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

            etBirthDateEdit.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();

            if(authenticate()==true){
                showDetails();


            }
            else {
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();

            }

        }

        public boolean authenticate(){

            return userLocalDatabase.getUserStatus();
        }

        public void showDetails(){
            User user=userLocalDatabase.getLoggedInUser();

            etFirstNameEdit.setText(user.firstName);
            etLastNameEdit.setText(user.lastName);
            etUsernameEdit.setText(user.userName);
            etQualificationEdit.setText(user.qualification);
            etPositionEdit.setText(user.position);
            etPasswordEdit.setText(user.password);
            etEmailEdit.setText(user.email);

            new downloadImage(etUsernameEdit.getText().toString()).execute();

        }



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch(v.getId()){

                case R.id.bSave2:



                    break;

                case R.id.bBack2:
                    startActivity(new Intent(this,SelectTask.class));
                    break;
                case R.id.userProfilePic:

                    Intent galleryIntent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,Result_Load_Image);




                    break;
                case R.id.bImageUpload:

                    Bitmap image=((BitmapDrawable) userProfilePic.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

                    new uploadImage(image,etUsernameEdit.getText().toString()).execute();



                    break;

            }


        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if(requestCode==Result_Load_Image && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null){

                Uri selectedImage= data.getData();

                userProfilePic.setImageURI(selectedImage);

            }

        }

        public class uploadImage extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {


            private Bitmap image;
            private String name;



            public uploadImage(Bitmap image,String name){
                this.image=image;
                this.name=name;

            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,byteArrayOutputStream);
                String encodedImage= Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(),Base64.DEFAULT);

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend1= new ArrayList<>();
                dataToSend1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",encodedImage));
                dataToSend1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",name));

                HttpParams httpRequestParams= getHttpRequestParams();

                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
                HttpPost post= new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "savePicture.php");

                try{
                    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend1));
                    httpClient.execute(post);

                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Image is uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        private HttpParams getHttpRequestParams(){
            HttpParams httpRequestParams= new BasicHttpParams();

            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, 1000 * 30);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams,1000 * 30);
            return httpRequestParams;






        }
        public class downloadImage extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Bitmap>{

            private String name;



            public downloadImage(String name){

                this.name=name;
            }


            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {


                String url= SERVER_ADDRESS+"proPictures/"+name+".JPG";


                try{
                    URLConnection connection= new URL(url).openConnection();

                    connection.setConnectTimeout(1000*30); 
                    connection.setReadTimeout(1000 * 30); 

                    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) connection.getContent(), null, null);






                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }





                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
                super.onPostExecute(bitmap);



                if(bitmap!=null){

                    userProfilePic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


                }

            }
        }




    }
```

here is my relavant xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.kasun.timetable.EditYourProfile"
    android:background="#303030">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1000dp"
        android:id="@+id/scroll">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/userProfilePic"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:background="#c6c4c4"

        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Upload "
        android:id="@+id/bImageUpload"

        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/userNameText"
        android:id="@+id/textView18"

        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/etUserNameEdit"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/FirstNameText"
        android:id="@+id/textView19"

        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/etFirstNameEdit"

        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/LastNameText"
        android:id="@+id/textView20"

        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/etLastNameEdit"

        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/Password"
            android:id="@+id/textView21"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"


            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/etPasswordEdit"

            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/Position"
        android:id="@+id/textView23"

        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/etPositionEdit"

        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/Email"
            android:id="@+id/textView24"

            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/etEmailEdit"

            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/Telephone"
            android:id="@+id/textView25"

            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/etTelephoneEdit"

            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/BDate"
            android:id="@+id/textView26"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/etBirthDateEdit"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/qualification"
            android:id="@+id/textView26"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/etQualificationEdit"/>

        <!--<DatePicker-->
            <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:id="@+id/datePicker"-->
            <!--android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/scroll"-->
            <!--android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"-->
            <!--android:layout_marginBottom="85dp" />-->






    </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>




    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/LogoutButtonText"
        android:id="@+id/bLogout2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center" />
        <!--android:layout_alignParentRight="@+id/bBack2"-->
    <!--android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/scroll"-->

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/BackButtonText"
        android:id="@+id/bBack2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/SaveButtonText"
        android:id="@+id/bSave2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bBack2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center" />





</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may come from the fact that you call showDetail on you onstart method which is called when you come back to your activity. Maybe it does something like that:
    activityToPickUpAPic-->PickUpAPic-->Go back to that activity-->
    Onstart-->May start to download your image->start on activity result-> charge       your new image->finish to download your image from the server

When you come back to your activity onStart is called again so you may want to change this method and call the download picture just at the Oncreate method.

Let me know it that's the problem ;)

Edit:

```
boolean isImageSet = false;
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode==Result_Load_Image && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null){

        Uri selectedImage= data.getData();

        userProfilePic.setImageURI(selectedImage);
        isImageSet = true;
    }
}
```

and:

```
if(bitmap!=null && !isImageSet){
    userProfilePic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

For the Test you could just comment

```
//userProfilePic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: yeah I also feel like that, but I can't find any call to the `onStart` method once after the image is selected by the user, can you specify exactly how the `onStart` method is called after selecting the image is done. OK I'll call it in `onCreate` and let you know the results

Comment: Nope, it isn't working. When we put the line `        new downloadImage(etUsernameEdit.getText().toString()).execute();` in the `onCreate()` method, there is no values to be get from the `etUsernameEdit` as values for it is set in `onStart()` through `showDetails()`, are there any other ways to solve this

Comment: Try just for the debug first to see if the problem of the changing image is coming from here, so basically put the code back in your onStart but just make sure that download imageImage is gonna be called just one time. I edit my post for some exemple.

Comment: when boolean `isImageSet` is used it worked. Thankyou